# Is it possible to view the application closed from the task manager in the even viewer logs or by any other mechanisms

Tags: windows, visual-c++, crash, freeze, taskmanager

I want to know whether my application has crashed at user machine or user killed it from the task manager.
What i know is if the application is crashed then it can be verified from the event viewer logs since the system logs the crash.
Similarly is there a way to figure out the application killed from the task manager? Any logs or mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to monitor the application and call GetExitCode via
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx
This will tell you the exit code. Success is typically 0, killed from task manager is 1. This may not differentiate between a crash though and killed from task manager, you'd have to test on your system, but at least you know to check the event logs if exit code is 1.

Crashes are logged to the event log, kills from task manager are not. In that case you'll need your own utility to monitor or use gflags.exe from the debugging tools installed: http://techibee.com/sysadmins/find-out-who-killed-a-process-in-windows/2286

Comment: Thank you. But i can't add a new code changes or install new exe at the customer machine. Is there any other way to audit the applications killed from the task manager. Does windows audit/logs this information. –

Comment: ah I see. On Windows 10  (not sure of your version) I don't see that task manager kills are logged. I'm dbl checking now.

Comment: Nope - you can't get this info without additional software, either your own or using this (but requires another utility to run) http://techibee.com/sysadmins/find-out-who-killed-a-process-in-windows/2286

Comment: Thank you very much. this tool looks promising. I will try out this tool if they say OK to install this.

Comment: It helped. Thank you. Did bit modifications in the approach. Instead of using the gflag.exe i m using the below registry setting  to avoid any mistakes than can happen with the gflag.exe since it has so many other options. This script does the same task as gflag.exe          [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\applicationnametobemonitored]
"GlobalFlag"=dword:0000200